# MySQL case-when-then (or other ways) to check values of multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, switch-statement

I request some help with MySQL when-then statement to fetch all the sid from the table after comparing multiple records having same sid but different cid-data values:

```
flag    sid cid data
----    --- --- ----
1       300 1   john
1       300 2   john_email
1       300 3   77500
1       300 4   ok

1       301 1   jack
1       301 2   john_email
1       301 3   72210
1       301 4   notok
```

Here for each sid, I need to check if (sid=2 has data=john_email) AND (sid=4 has data=ok)
Only if both the conditions are satisfied, I return the sid. i.e. the output will be '300' only.

I am confused how to use the case-when-then and compare 'data' with 'john_email' and also compare data with 'ok' ... based on the cid values. Thanks for reading.

Comment: This is an Entity-Attribute-Value table.  They are notoriously poor in terms of performance and code-maintainability if queryng them as you are. If you can move back to a more normal table set up, I recommend that you do so.

Comment: @Dems not to mention that each record seems to have only these 4 attributes, nothing more, northing less. Variable attribute count, under some circumstances validates this option, but definitely not this case.

Comment: I too hate this. This is how Drupal webform data are stored :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
select sid
from your_table
group by sid
where (cid=2 and data='john_email')
or (cid=4 and data='ok')
having sum(cid=2)=1 and sum(data='john_email')=1
and sum(cid=4)=1 and sum(data='ok')=1
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c6a2/1)

Comment: wow, that's a quick solution! Not trivial to understand, but nevertheless a brilliant one!

Comment: The `OR` should be an `AND`, as the OP only wants SIDs where both conditions are met?

Comment: @Dems: Thanks for that. I missed it.

Comment: Oh, and `SUM(sid=` should be `SUM(cid=` in both cases.

Comment: @juergen d: I am trying to implement this. But what if the person's name (cid=1) has a data='ok'? i.e. how do we ensure the sum(data='ok')=1 refers to the data at cid=4 only?

Comment: That's awesome. I have implemented the same now. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You should join the table to itself, then you can check the condition in the two rows as if it was one row...

```
SELECT T1.sid
FROM MYTABLE T1
JOIN MYTABLE T2 ON T1.SID=T2.SID AND T1.CID=1 AND T2.CID=4
WHERE T1.DATA='john'
AND T2.DATA='ok'
```

Note that I used the CID values in the join clause, but you will have to adjust them if you want to join on different data rows...

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use a subquery and check if the value exists.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table outertable
WHERE
    ( cid=2 AND data='john_email' )
    AND
    EXISTS ( SELECT sid FROM table WHERE cid = 4 AND data = 'ok' AND sid = outertable.sid )
```

Comment: ... and that is what EXISTS is for! `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ( sid=2 AND data='john_email' ) AND EXISTS ( SELECT sid FROM table WHERE sid = 4 AND data = 'ok' )`

Comment: Still incorrect.  The `EXISTS` correlated sub-query MUST reference the inner query's SID.  At present the `EXISTS` is only testing whether there is **any** row that matches, for any `sid`.  You need to check that `THIS SID` has a match.

Comment: @Dems From mysql docs: `If a subquery returns any rows at all, EXISTS subquery is TRUE, and NOT EXISTS subquery is FALSE.` I do not have to match the `sid`.

Comment: First, you mean `cid=4`, not `sid=4`.  Second, if your outer query is processing `sid=301` your EXISTS query will check the *whole* table, see that there is a match for `sid=300` and so return true.  In effect you are saying *[If **any sid** has a row of `cid=4 AND data='ok'` then all is good]* but what you need to be testing is *[If **this sid** has a row of `cid=4 AND data='ok'` then all is good]*.  Trust me, or set up a SQL and test it.  Do you get the same results as the OP requested using the OPs example data?  *[The answer is `no` by the way.]*

Comment: @Dems You are absolutely right, I just misread you. :) I updated to implement the right IDs.